# Regex greedy positive look-behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input which consists of a calculation followed by something else. Example:

```
3 * 5+2jdf344*23sd
```

I want to use a Regex which returns `jdf344*23sd`; the first calculation-breaking match.

I tried:

```
/(?<=(( ?[0-9]+ ?[\*\-\/\+\=\%\^])+ ?[0-9]+ ?)).+/
```

as the opposite of:

```
/( ?[0-9]+ ?[\*\-\/\+\=\%\^])+ ?[0-9]+ ?/
```

But this also selects the part after the first multiplication. The reason is that the positive look-behind is already true for +2.

The problem is that I don't know the length of the calculation.
Edit: also the calculation can have spaces between the numbers and operators, but not numbers - if calculation part ends with a operator it should (dosent have to be, but would be nice) also be inside the match

I hope you can help me,
thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting, is it (3 * 5+2)?

Comment: Will it always end in jdf344*23sd? or something predictable?

Comment: Probably doing the opposite will be easier - see [`^(?:[\s+\/*-]|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/999eeZ/1).

Comment: I am expecting the part which is not the calculation, and I dont know what it will be

Answer (score -2):

If you find that you need just the calculation - try this:

```
/([-\/+0-9\s\*+]*)/
```

Here is the regex101 test:

```
https://regex101.com/r/FZTp5T/5
```